# how does this C code with input through < work? (K&R)

Tags: c, shell

```
$ ./main < input
```

If I were to check for new lines in python, I would open the file and then analyze the lines, but this almost seems like magic.

```
int main(){

int c, nl;

nl = 0;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    if (c == '\n')
        nl++;
printf("%d\n", nl);

return 0;
}
```

How does it know to accept any input file without being stated within the code?

Comment: This is not valid c, main has to be "int main(void)" or "int main(int argc, char* argv[])"

Comment: And the code only reads stdin, it doesn't read any file.

Comment: @Fredrik It's not invalid. And all major compilers support `int main()`.

Comment: This was how it was written in the book.

Comment: You can do the same in Python if you write a program that reads from stdin.

Comment: @klutt Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: @klutt C standard says otherwise

Comment: @Fredrik Please cite where it specifically says it's not valid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<` symbol in the shell is an *input redirection*.  It states that the contents of the given file `input` in this case, will be read as stdin.

So any function such as `getchar` that reads from stdin will actually be reading from the file `input` in this case.

A similar program in Python would also use functions that read from stdin instead of from a file.

Comment: Nice answer, but you should add something about that this is possible for regular user input functions in python too